# Openshift Project hide Elasticsearch Route

Tags: openshift

I am new to OpenShift so apologies in advance if this question is not very clear.
I have a project starting in Openshift and will use the Elasticsearch provided docker image as a data store.

ElasiticSearch is bound only to local host by default when installed, and if I was running app on a server I would keep this configuration so as not to expose ElasticSearch interface as connectivity only required by the application, no need to expose outside of project.

If I make a route for Elasticsearch without changing it's default config, it is accessible to other Pods in project but also outside of the project,  like the main application. Is it possible to make a route that is internal to the project only so that Elasticsearch interface is not accessible outside of the project or by other means  ? Or a way to have a common local host address between pods/applications ?
I tried to group the services but still not available.
Any support to put me in right direction really appreciated.

Comment: Internal comms should be done via service name. Use a route to expose the service to the outside world.

Comment: thanks, fq service name looks good!